# Align input controls on page

Tags: html, css

I have a form with 4 textboxes, a checkbox and a select with their labels on their left.  Here's my code:

```
<fieldset class="form-field">
        <legend>
            <label class="form-field k-checkbox">Parent Material</label>
        </legend>
        <ul class="form-field">
            <li>
                <label for="use_test_certificate" class="form-field">Use Test Certificate</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="use_test_certificate" class="k-checkbox form-field" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="parent_material" class="form-field">Material</label>
                <select name="parent_material" class="form-field"></select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="proof_stress" class="form-field">0.2% Proof Stress</label>
                <input type="text" name="proof_stress" size="24" maxlength="23" style="width:170px;" class="k-textbox form-field" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="do_weld_calculation" class="form-field">Do Weld Calculation</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="do_weld_calculation" class="k-checkbox form-field" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="weld_redistribution_factor" class="form-field">Weld Redistribution Factor</label>
                <input type="text" name="weld_redistribution_factor" size="24" maxlength="23" style="width:170px;" class="k-textbox form-field" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
```

Problem is that the select displays next to the checkbox and not next to it's label.  And when I increase the window size it jumps up to next to my first textbox.  How can I tell it to show next to it's label.  I'm not a CSS expert.  I normally can work things out for myself, but this one baffles me completely.  Any help is appreciated.

Amanda

Comment: It isn't doing it **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/xNWLR/1/)**. Can you please include your CSS so we can better help you?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you haven't shown your CSS, I might as well show you the ideal solution using nothing but form elements :)

Note how I have changed the `name` attributes to `id`. The `id`, which needs to be unique, is used to identify the corresponding `label` by means of the labels `for` attribute.

[Have a look at this fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/xNWLR/2/)

CSS

```
fieldset {
    width: 500px;
}
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
input, select {
    display: block;
    float: left;   
    margin: 10px;
}
input[type=text] {
    width: 170px;
}
```

HTML

```
<fieldset class="form-field">
    <legend>Parent Material</legend>
        <label for="use_test_certificate" class="form-field">Use Test Certificate</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="use_test_certificate" class="k-checkbox form-field" />

        <label for="parent_material" class="form-field">Material</label>
        <select id="parent_material" class="form-field"></select>

        <label for="proof_stress" class="form-field">0.2% Proof Stress</label>
        <input type="text" id="proof_stress" maxlength="23" class="k-textbox form-field" />

        <label for="do_weld_calculation" class="form-field">Do Weld Calculation</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="do_weld_calculation" class="k-checkbox form-field" />

        <label for="weld_redistribution_factor" class="form-field">Weld Redistribution Factor</label>
        <input type="text" id="weld_redistribution_factor" maxlength="23" class="k-textbox form-field" />
</fieldset>
```